# Storybook won't load CSS from node-modules

Tags: webpack, storybook

I've trying to set up my storybook to display a Carousel component.

I'm using [this carousel](https://github.com/akiran/react-slick), along with styled-components.

I'm importing my external CSS files as follow :

```
import 'slick-carousel/slick/slick.css'
import 'slick-carousel/slick/slick-theme.css'
```

and here is my very basic webpack config

```
// storybook/webpack.config.js

const path = require("path");
module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader"
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ["css-loader", "sass-loader"],
        include: [
          path.resolve(__dirname, "../src"),
          path.resolve(__dirname, "../node_modules")
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    modules: [path.resolve(__dirname, "../src"), "node_modules"],
    extensions: [".js"]
  }
};
```

This does not work, and I cannot get any styling on my Carousel.

Did I do something wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `style-loader`:

```
use: ["style-loader", "css-loader", "sass-loader"]
```

Hopefully this will solve your problem.